# Как перекодировать формат файла при архивации тела запроса в zip (jmeter)?

Tags: java, jmeter

При архивации тела запроса в формате хмл в зип архив, файл записывается в кодировке unsi, то есть кириллица, которой в выписке очень много, не отображается корректно. Пробовал прописать дефолтную кодировку через джметр пропертис, не помогает, пробовал через семплер прописать логику prev.setDataEncoding("UTF-8"), все равно файл пакуется в анси, также пробовал в джметр.бат определить prev.setDataEncoding("UTF-8"), все равно не помогает, может есть какие то варианты сделать принудительную запись в ютф8 в самой логике кода?

```
def destination = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File('request' + ${__Random(100000,200000,)} + '.zip')))

destination.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(prev.getSampleLabel() + '.xml'))
destination << prev.getSamplerData().bytes


destination.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл записывается в дефолтной кодировке для JVM (значение системной проперти [file.encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)), которую можно задать в файле [system.properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Если вы хотите поменять кодировку принудительно только для вашего куска кода, который делает ZIP архив - это тоже можно:

на уровне конструктора [ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

```
def destination = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File('request' + ${__Random(100000,200000,)} + '.zip')), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

и при [записи запроса в файл](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset))

```
destination << prev.getSamplerData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: пробовал добавить гетбайтс, тогда пишет, что архив поврежден, и не удается вообще его открыть